# Reading in Images and resizing them efficiently

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-resizing

I try to read in a bunch of images (more than 180k) and resize them to new height and a new width. I use the code below and it works for a small number of images but for a large number, the kernel dies... So, is there a more efficient way to resize the images? Maybe without reading the images in?

```
 folders = glob.glob(r'path\to\images\*')
 imagenames_list = []
    for folder in folders:
        for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.png'):
            imagenames_list.append(f)
    read_images = []        

    for image in imagenames_list:
        read_images.append(cv2.imread(image))

    def resize_images(img, new_width, new_height):
        size = (new_width, new_height)
        resized_img = cv2.resize(img, size)
        return resized_img

    resized_img = [resize_images(img, new_width=128, new_height=32) for img in read_images]
```

Comment: You could use imagemagick's convert utility to save them on disk the size you need them and then only load the resized images as you need them

Comment: In this case, preprocessing with a command line tool as @shortcipher3 suggest is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are loading around 180,000 images into the `read_images` list. That is a lot of images and is likely filling up the RAM and killing the kernel as well.

Since you have not mentioned what you intend to do with these resized images, I can suggest two things you might want to try instead.

- create a `resize_and_save(image_path, new_size, save_path)` to load, save and release the image right away. You can use this for every image in `imagenames_list`
- if you are using this to create batches for training, load only as many images as necessary to prepare one batch and resize only those images

Comment: I would like to train a neural network with the data, but I do only use 60% of them. To get the right images for training I actually have to merge the images with another dataset. I don't know how to do this when using batch sizes? I think in that case the first option would be suitable, what do you mean?